# CFML - Parse a String - Find Variables

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I know this is fairly simple.  But I can't find my cut paste code or something that works.

I am encrypting a string.

```
<cfset encrlink = encrypt("uid=WWWDDD&email=BOBEMAIL@BOB.COM", APPLICATION.AesKeyForMails, "AES", "HEX")>
```

Which works fine. And then I decrypt it.

```
<cfset dncrlink = decrypt("#encrlink#", APPLICATION.AesKeyForMails, "AES", "HEX")>
<cfoutput>[#dncrlink#]</cfoutput>
```

Which works fine.  Gives out "uid=WWWDDD&email=BOBEMAIL@BOB.COM"

I need to get "uid=" and "email=" out and use as variables of the decrypted string.  By parsing.  I'm just a bit stuck.  Is it Trim? Find? I kinda have this working.  But not sure how to build the cfset.

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset theUrl = "#dncrlink#" />
    <cfloop list="#theUrl#" index="URLPiece" delimiters="&">
        <br>#listFirst(urlPiece, "=")# = #listLast(urlPiece, "=")# <br> 
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: The logic you are using seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do a CFIF for the Variables.

```
      <cfloop list="#theUrl#" index="URLPiece" delimiters="&">
         <br>#listFirst(urlPiece, "=")# = #listLast(urlPiece, "=")# <br>    
         <cfif #listFirst(urlPiece, "=")# is "uid"><cfset uid = "#listLast(urlPiece, "=")#"></cfif>
         <cfif #listFirst(urlPiece, "=")# is "email"><cfset email = "#listLast(urlPiece, "=")#"></cfif>
       </cfloop>
```

Answer (score 1):

Too long for comments ...

You could also "genericize" the logic into something which could be used with any query string. Extract the parameters and store them in a structure

```
<cfset dncrlink = "uid=WWWDDD&email=BOBEMAIL@BOB.COM">

<cfset params = {}>
<cfloop list="#dncrlink#" index="elem" delimiters="&">
    <cfset params[ elem.listFirst("=") ] = elem.listRest("=")>
</cfloop>
```

Then to access parameter values:

```
<cfoutput>
    uid = #params.uid#<br>
    email = #params.email#<br>
</cfoutput>
```